# fabric ensemble with active/passive containers

Tags: jbossfuse, fabric8

I have the following problem and hope someone may help me out.

I had to migrate from rh jboss soa-p to rh fuse.
I was able to create a fabric ensemble with three nodes and also use the gateway profile for the load-balancing of rest services.
Now, I have to deploy a java application that must be running only on the master nodes of the ensemble. If the master falls, then this application must start running automatically on one of the other nodes (the node that will become the new master).
How can I achive this?

Thank you
Barbara

Answer (score 0):

If you use Camel, then there is a fuse `master` [1] component that only runs if its the master, and automatic failover to another node if the master dies / is stopped.

[1] - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Apache_Camel_Component_Reference/Master.html

Comment: I read about the master component, but it is possible to use it outside a camel route?
My problem is that the application I need to deploy it's a legacy jar, I can modify very little of it. This application read from a DB and then send data to a configurable destination (it can be another db or a queue). So, maybe, I can modify the destination... but since it's not camel, I cannot write "master:" ... does exist any other syntax?